# FormatError: not a 7z file

Tags: python, python-3.x, 7zip

```
with open (sourcefile,'rb') as i:
    with open (targetfile,'wb') as o:
        i.seek(0)
        s = py7zlib.Archive7z(i)
        while True:
            tmp = s.read(65536)
            if tmp :
                o.write(tmp)
                continue
            else:
                break
```

I get a error FormatError: not a 7z file
**s = py7zlib.Archive7z(i)**

When I compress a file using pylzma in python 3.3 running on Windows 7.

The file I am trying to compress is a XML file. Even this doesn't work:

```
with open (sourcefile,'rb') as i:
    with open (targetfile,'wb') as o:
        i.seek(0)
        s = py7zlib.Archive7z(o)
        while True:
            tmp = s.read(65536)
            if tmp:
                o.write(tmp)
                continue
            else:
                break
```

Error:

> ```py
> UnsupportedOperation: read
> **raise FormatError('not a 7z file')**
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You are constructing a Archive7z on the XML file, not the destination file.

To correct your code: replace `i` with `o` in `s = py7zlib.Archive7z(i)` and `s` with `i` in `tmp = s.read(65536)`.

Comment: My answer is correct; Archive7z accepts the 7z file, not the uncompressed file.